# host different frameworks IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6, windows-2003-webserver

I have windows server 2003 with IIS6 installed. I installed both framework 2 and 4 on the IIS. The applications that using Framework2 are running perfectly , when I try to host framework4 application I get this error:

The resource cannot be found

Please advise,

Thank you

Comment: Is the .NET4 application an ASP.NET MVC application? Then you have to go through additional steps to get it working on IIS6 and I'd rather suggest trying to get a host with IIS7 or newer since running on IIS6 is quite a hassle and far from optimal.

Comment: No, it is webforms. I solved the problem by creating a different application pool on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a different application pool on IIS